# jquery clone table and keep the same dimensions

Tags: jquery, css

I am having an issue that I am hoping is easy to fix.

I have an html table which I am cloning using

```
var clonedTable = $("#mytable").clone();
```

I then append my cloned table to a div

```
$("#mydiv").append(clonedTable)
```

If I then remove all the  from my cloned table and only keep the header, 
the dimensions of the table change.

What is the easiest way for me to keep the dimensions of my cloned table the same as the original table after removing all the  and only keeping the header ?

Comment: What decides the width of your original table? The content?

Comment: enclose tags with ` , for example, when you use `<tr>` Otherwise, nobody can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS and style the table the way you wish, with or without content.

It sounds like the table size is dependent on the contents, so once those are removed it goes back to "auto sizing".

Another alternative is to get the size of the original table's columns and apply them as width styles to the clone, but this involves some further processing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are relying on the default table width algorithm that browsers use. You should set the width of the table element explicity, aka:

```
 <table style="width: 400px;">
```

OR

```
 <table style="width: 50%;">
```

So the table remains that width even in another element.